# Stock ageing with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stock, inventory

I have a table content as below, where 'ItemName' is the name of the items, 'CurrentStock' is the current stock quantity of items and all other columns are the sum of stock-in and stock-out on that year. Now I want to replace all negative value with 0 and adjust those negative value with the positive value in FIFO order. Can any one guide me how do that in SQL Server.

[image]

Here is the Expected Result
[image]

Initially I tried like this

```
select ItemName,CurrentStock, 
case when (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)<0 and (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)>=0 then (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore) 
    when (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)<0 and (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)>=0 THEN (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)
    when (Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)<0 and (Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)>=0 THEN (Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)
    when (Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)<0 and (Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)>=0 THEN (Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)
    when (Qnty2014+Qnty2013)<0 and (Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)>=0 THEN (Qnty2014+Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore)
    when Qnty2013 <0 and Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore >=0 then Qnty2013+Qnty2012andBefore 
else Qnty2012andBefore end as Qnty2012andBefore,
case when Qnty2013<0 then 0
    when (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014)<0 and (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)>=0 then (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013) 
    when (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014)<0 and (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)>=0 THEN (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)
    when (Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014)<0 and (Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)>=0 THEN (Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)
    when (Qnty2015+Qnty2014)<0 and (Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)>=0 THEN (Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013)
    when (Qnty2014)<0 and (Qnty2014+Qnty2013)>=0 THEN (Qnty2014+Qnty2013)
else Qnty2013 end as Qnty2013,
case when Qnty2014<0 then 0
    when (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015)<0 and (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014)>=0 then (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014) 
    when (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015)<0 and (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014)>=0 THEN (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014)
    when (Qnty2016+Qnty2015)<0 and (Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014)>=0 THEN (Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014)
    when (Qnty2015)<0 and (Qnty2015+Qnty2014)>=0 THEN (Qnty2015+Qnty2014)
else Qnty2014 end as Qnty2014,
case when Qnty2015<0 then 0
    when (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016)<0 and (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015)>=0 then (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015) 
    when (Qnty2017+Qnty2016)<0 and (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015)>=0 THEN (Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015)
    when (Qnty2016)<0 and (Qnty2016+Qnty2015)>=0 THEN (Qnty2016+Qnty2015)
else Qnty2015 end as Qnty2015,
    case when Qnty2016<0 then 0
    when (Qnty2018+Qnty2017)<0 and (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016)>=0 then (Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016) 
    when (Qnty2017)<0 and (Qnty2017+Qnty2016)>=0 THEN ( Qnty2017+Qnty2016)
else Qnty2016 end as Qnty2016,
case when Qnty2017<0 then 0
    when (Qnty2018)< 0 and (Qnty2018+Qnty2017)>=0 then (Qnty2018+Qnty2017) 
else Qnty2017 end as Qnty2017,
case when Qnty2018<0 then 0 else Qnty2018 end as Qnty2018 FROM StockTable
```

but it gave wrong output like this
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Eek, do you have the option to normalize the table? This would be so much more simple with a quantity and date...

Comment: @JacobH could you please explain how to do it, thanks.

Comment: I'm unable to understand this **Now I want to replace all negative value with 0 and adjust those negative value with the positive value in FIFO order**. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Mr. Rahman, I am trying to explain what I want. Stock in hand in 2012 was 4246, In 2013 no stock in only 446 stock out, so after 2013 my stock in hand was (4246-446)=3800 which is stock from 2012. In 2014 no stock out but 1233 stock in so my stock in hand is now (3800 +1233)=5033 where 3800  from 2012 and 1233 from 2014. Again in 2015 no stock in, 1139 stock out, so after 2015 my stock in hand is (5033-1139)=3894, where (3800-1139)=2661 from 2012 and 1233 from 2014. So on for 2016,2017 and 2018. I don't know it is explaining the scenario or make you more confused. Anyway thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two solutions for this.

1. Using #Temp table as shown below

   ```
   SELECT ItemName,CurrentStock,
   CASE when Qnty2018<0 THEN 0 ELSE Qnty2018 END as Qnty2018,
   CASE when Qnty2017<0 THEN 0 ELSE Qnty2017 END as Qnty2017,
   CASE when Qnty2016<0 THEN 0 ELSE Qnty2016 END as Qnty2016,
   CASE when Qnty2015<0 THEN 0 ELSE Qnty2015 END as Qnty2015,
   CASE when Qnty2014<0 THEN 0 ELSE Qnty2014 END as Qnty2014,
   CASE when Qnty2013<0 THEN 0 ELSE Qnty2013 END as Qnty2013,
   CASE when Qnty2012andBefore<0 THEN 0 ELSE Qnty2012andBefore END as Qnty2012andBefore INTO #Temp FROM StockTable

   update #Temp set Qnty2018=CurrentStock WHERE Qnty2018<>0 AND Qnty2017=0 AND Qnty2016=0 AND Qnty2015=0 AND Qnty2014=0 AND Qnty2013=0 AND Qnty2012andBefore=0
   update #Temp set Qnty2017=CurrentStock-Qnty2018 WHERE Qnty2017<>0 AND Qnty2016=0 AND Qnty2015=0 AND Qnty2014=0 AND Qnty2013=0 AND Qnty2012andBefore=0
   update #Temp set Qnty2016=CurrentStock-Qnty2018+Qnty2017 WHERE Qnty2016<>0 AND Qnty2015=0 AND Qnty2014=0 AND Qnty2013=0 AND Qnty2012andBefore=0
   update #Temp set Qnty2015=CurrentStock-Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016 WHERE Qnty2015<>0 AND Qnty2014=0 AND Qnty2013=0 AND Qnty2012andBefore=0
   update #Temp set Qnty2014=CurrentStock-Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015 WHERE Qnty2014<>0 AND Qnty2013=0 AND Qnty2012andBefore=0
   update #Temp set Qnty2013=CurrentStock-Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014 WHERE Qnty2013<>0 AND Qnty2012andBefore=0
   update #Temp set Qnty2012andBefore=CurrentStock-Qnty2018+Qnty2017+Qnty2016+Qnty2015+Qnty2014+Qnty2013 WHERE Qnty2012andBefore<>0
   SELECT * FROM #Temp
   ```

   2.Using Cursor, You could iterate on row basis and write the logic. since this is not recommended in SQL, use it only if you don't have other option.

Comment: @sticky bit your suggestion could lead to more number of columns then expected, and the order of columns could be  misleading

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am going to try both of them.

Comment: I am sorry for this late reply. I used temp table and update it as per my requirement and it is giving me the accurate result thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: That specific code did not worked but the approach definitely worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think you need the sums in the `CASE`s for? Given your example, it seems to me, that one `CASE` on each individual column has the effect you want. For the calculation of `Qnty2012andBefore` subtract from `CurrentStock` again individually applying the `CASE` on the summands. Like that:

```
SELECT ItemName,
       CurrentStock,
       CASE
         WHEN Qnty2018 < 0
           THEN 0
         ELSE
           Qnty2018
       END Qnty2018,
       ...
       CASE
         WHEN Qnty2013 < 0
           THEN 0
         ELSE
           Qnty2013
       END Qnty2013,
       CurrentStock
       -
       CASE
         WHEN Qnty2018 < 0
           THEN 0
         ELSE
           Qnty2018
       END
       ...
       -
       CASE
         WHEN Qnty2013 < 0
           THEN 0
         ELSE
           Qnty2013
       END Qnty2012andBefore
       FROM StockTable;
```